# Image upload with React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file-upload

I am trying to make an UI that allows the user to upload one single image from their device. They can either upload it via the choose file button or use the drag/drop option. I have made it work thus far. The user is also presented with a remove image button after uploading. The issue is here. Although it removes the uploaded image, the user is automatically asked to upload an image again. How can we solve this? Thanks for your help.

Edit: It seems like the issue you're facing is that after removing the uploaded image, the user is prompted again to upload an image. This is because the state variable selectedImage is being set to null when the "Remove Image" button is clicked, which triggers the re-rendering of the component and causes the input field to reset. (ChatGPT)
However, the solution it provides does not solve the issue.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Search.css';

interface AppProps {}

const Search: React.FC<AppProps> = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<File | null>(null);

  const handleImageUpload = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (file) {
      setSelectedImage(file);
    }
  };

  const handleImageRemove = () => {
    setSelectedImage(null);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLLabelElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleDragEnter = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLLabelElement>) => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add('drag-active');
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLLabelElement>) => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove('drag-active');
  };

  const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLLabelElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dropContainer = e.currentTarget;
    dropContainer.classList.remove('drag-active');

    const file = e.dataTransfer.files?.[0];
    if (file) {
      setSelectedImage(file);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="square top-left">
        {selectedImage ? <img src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)} alt="Uploaded" /> : null}
      </div>
      <div className="square bottom-left">
        <label
          htmlFor="images"
          className={`drop-container ${selectedImage ? 'with-image' : ''} ${selectedImage && 'image-present'}`}
          id="dropcontainer"
          onDragOver={handleDragOver}
          onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
          onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
          onDrop={handleDrop}
        >
          <div>
            <span className="drop-title">Drag&Drop your image here</span>
            <center>or</center>
          </div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageUpload} id="images" />
          {selectedImage && <button onClick={handleImageRemove}>Remove Image</button>}
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="square top-right red-background">
        <h1>For Now</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="square bottom-right">
        <button>Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```